# Chart js custom single tooltip not working

Tags: javascript, tooltip, customization, chart.js

Hi i would like to set the tooltips of my chart so that only the label and nothing else is displayed. Unfortunately, the x-value is still being displayed as you can see here: https://1drv.ms/i/s!As59C5Mmd0nahr4ENuppEupBDAbqqw

this is the code that is being executed at the beginning when i create the chart:

```
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
        label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
            return data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make font size zero like this:

```
tooltips: {
    titleFontSize: 0
}
```